# Enum class não aceitando checagem

Tags: c++, enums

Bem estou com uma dúvida estou iniciando agora no C++

estou usando um enum class:

```
enum class TYPE_ENTER {
    ENTER_OK = 0x1,
    ENTER_WARNING = 0x2
};
```

porém na hora de eu compilar a função ocorre erro C2678 na função.

```
int EnterSession::CheckEnter(char *type, int id) {

    if (*(int*)type == TYPE_ENTER::ENTER_OK) {// Ocorre Erro em ==
        //Mycode
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Na hora de compilar ocorre erro em **==**, é possível manter o enum class ou vou ter que usar enum normal ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você deve converter seu enum class para INT também, ou então converter a variável type para o tipo de seu enum class, e você está fazendo o casting errado.

Para converter string ou char para INT, você deve usar a função atoi();

O código ficaria assim:

```
    int nType = atoi(type);

    std::cout << nType;
    if (nType == (int) TYPE_ENTER::ENTER_OK) {
        //código
    }
```

Comment: só pra entender, se fosse pra mim converter o type em vez do enum como ficaria ? eu tentei usando `TYPE_ENTER TestType = (int)type;` mais ocorre C2440

Comment: Amigo, como você está fazendo cast para int, o TestType deve ser INT e não TYPE_ENTER.
Você não pode comparar um tipo int com um ENUM CLASS sem fazer o cast.

Comment: Se `char *type` não apontar pra um objeto do tipo `int`, a expressão `*(int *)type` resulta em comportamento indefinido.

Comment: A resposta foi corrigida com os devidos testes feitos.